# How can I avoid cyclic dependency which occurs on importing the store while using easy-peasy redux library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, easy-peasy

Importing stores after creating it causes this problem.

***store.ts***

```
/**
 * Author: Rahul Shetty
 *
 * The central redux store of our app is created and exported to be used from
 * here.
 */
import { createStore, persist } from 'easy-peasy';
import { services } from '@services/index';
import storage from '@utils/storage';
import { Entities } from 'types/entities';
import storeModel from '@models/index';

// Add any additional store enhancers
let storeEnhancers: any[] = [];

if (__DEV__) {
  const reactotron = require('./reactotron.config').default;
  // @types/ws
  const reactotronConfig = reactotron();

  // Global variable. Use it to log your variable and you can see the result in reactotrons
  (global as any).tronlog = (value: any) => reactotronConfig.log('TRON', value);
  storeEnhancers = [...storeEnhancers, reactotronConfig.createEnhancer()];
}

export const store = createStore(
  persist(storeModel, {
    whitelist: [Entities.LANGUAGES],
    storage,
  }),
  {
    injections: { ...services },
    enhancers: [...storeEnhancers],
  },
); //  create our store

if (__DEV__) {
  // @types/webpack-env
  if (module.hot) {
    // At times the app breaks. Just reload and start again
    module.hot.accept('../models', () => {
      store.reconfigure(storeModel); //  Here is the magic
    });
  }
}

export default store;
```

The important line to note in the above code snippet is `injections: { ...services }`. It injects all the services as functions used to make API calls.

***services/index.ts***

```
import * as placesServices from './places';
import * as appointmentServices from './appointment';

export const services = {
  placesServices,
  appointmentServices,
};
```

***services/places.ts***

```
import { PlaceServices } from 'types/places';
import { customerAPIInstance } from './api';

export const getPlaces: PlaceServices['getPlaces'] = () =>
  customerAPIInstance.get('/branches');

export const favoritePlace: PlaceServices['favoritePlace'] = (info) =>
  customerAPIInstance.put('/favorite', info);
```

The below-given code snippet creates a dependency cycle.

***services/api.ts***

```
/**
 * Author: Rahul Shetty
 *
 * API Wrapper for the app
 */
import Config from 'react-native-config';
import axios, { Method, AxiosInstance } from 'axios';
import { Entity } from 'types/entities';
import store from '@store/index';
import { ActionCreator } from 'easy-peasy';
import { MetaPayload } from 'types/meta';

type StoreOptions = {
  setPending: ActionCreator<MetaPayload>;
  setError: ActionCreator<MetaPayload>;
  resetError: ActionCreator<MetaPayload>;
};

type APIOptions = {
  method: Method;
  url: string;
  data: DynamicObject;
  entity?: Entity;
};

const { BASE_URL } = Config;

export const customerAPIInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
  timeout: 20000,
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
});

export const apiConfig = (
  apiInstance: AxiosInstance,
  storeOptions: StoreOptions,
) => async <T>(apiOptions: APIOptions): Promise<T> => {
  const { method, url, data, entity } = apiOptions;
  const { setPending, setError, resetError } = storeOptions;

  /**
   * if the developer doesn't wanna track the asynchronous states, then we avoid
   * calling store actions by not passing the entity name
   */
  if (entity) {
    setPending({
      pending: true,
      entity,
    });
  }

  try {
    const result = await apiInstance({
      method,
      url,
      data,
    });

    // Reset any error if the API call was successful
    if (entity) {
      resetError({
        entity,
      });
    }

    return result.data;
  } catch (err) {
    const message =
      err.response && err.response.data && err.response.data.message
        ? err.response.data.message
        : err.message;

    // Save the error related data if the API call was unsuccessful
    if (entity) {
      setError({
        error: {
          message,
          statusCode: err.status || 500,
        },
        entity,
      });
    }

    throw Error(err);
  } finally {
    // The API call has either successfully resolved or has been rejected.
    // In either case, pending should be set to false
    if (entity) {
      setPending({
        pending: false,
        entity,
      });
    }
  }
};

export const CustomerAPI = apiConfig(customerAPIInstance, {
  setPending: store.getActions().metadata.setPending,
  setError: store.getActions().metadata.setError,
  resetError: store.getActions().metadata.resetError,
});
```

As you might have observed in the code snippet available above, I am trying to handle error and loading state from a single point using [easy-peasy](https://easy-peasy.now.sh/) redux actions which are available via the store.

To be specific, `import store from '@store/index';` creates the dependency cycle.

But, since injections are nothing but services which in turn uses the store, a dependency cycle is formed.

> Store -> injections -> services -> places -> API Instance -> Store

I do have a solution. I could pass the actions from the methods calling the services. For example,

***models/places.ts***

```
const placesModel = {
  fetchPlaces: thunk(async(actions, payload, { injections, getStoreActions }) => {
    injections.getPlaces(payload, getStoreActions);
  })
};
```

But, with the approach shown above, I would have to keep passing the store actions as a second parameter to all the services.

How can I break the dependency cycle by sharing the store actions to make sure the API Instance can set error and loading state from a single location?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is importing the `store.ts` file as it is dependent on services. I made the below-given changes to get rid of this issue.

I created `async-handler.ts` and added the following code:

```
import { Entity } from 'types/entities';
import type { Actions, Meta, State, Dispatch } from 'easy-peasy';
import { Services } from 'types/services';
import { StoreModel } from 'types/model';

// @TODO: Simplify the repetitive types
type HandleAsyncStates = <Model extends object = {}, Payload = void>(
  callback: (
    actions: Actions<Model>,
    payload: Payload,
    helpers: {
      dispatch: Dispatch<StoreModel>;
      getState: () => State<Model>;
      getStoreActions: () => Actions<StoreModel>;
      getStoreState: () => State<StoreModel>;
      injections: Services;
      meta: Meta;
    },
  ) => Promise<any>,
) => (
  actions: Actions<Model>,
  payload: Payload,
  helpers: {
    dispatch: Dispatch<StoreModel>;
    getState: () => State<Model>;
    getStoreActions: () => Actions<StoreModel>;
    getStoreState: () => State<StoreModel>;
    injections: Services;
    meta: Meta;
  },
) => Promise<any>;

export const handleAsyncStates: HandleAsyncStates = (callback) => async (
  actions,
  payload,
  helpers,
) => {
  const { getStoreActions, meta } = helpers;
  const { setPending, resetError, setError } = getStoreActions().metadata;

  const entity = meta.path[0] as Entity;

  // Start the pendinng state
  setPending({
    pending: true,
    entity,
  });

  try {
    // Perform you API or async tasks inside the callback, and return the promise
    const result = await callback(actions, payload, helpers);

    // reset any error if it has been set
    resetError(entity);

    return result;
  } catch (err) {
    const message =
      err.response && err.response.data && err.response.data.message
        ? err.response.data.message
        : err.message;

    const errData = {
      message,
      statusCode: err.status || 500,
    };

    // Save the error related data in the store if the API call was unsuccessful
    setError({
      error: errData,
      entity,
    });

    return errData;
  } finally {
    // The API call has either successfully resolved or has been rejected.
    // In either case, pending should be set to false
    setPending({
      pending: false,
      entity,
    });
  }
};
```

This async handler which acts as a HOC is then passed to the store thunk like so:

```
  fetchAndSaveNearbyPlaces: thunk(
    handleAsyncStates<PlacesModel, PlaceAPIOption>(
      async (actions, payload, { injections }) => {
        const { placesServices } = injections;
        const response = await placesServices.getPlaces<PlaceListResponse>();

        actions.saveNearbyPlaces(response.data.result);

        return response;
      },
    ),
  ),
```

The store thunk provides the necessary actions and services required to perform the common store actions such as tracking the API async states and eliminates the need to import `store.ts` altogether.